# z-index is auto after defined to other value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this two divs and is intended 'a'  to stay above 'b' as set by z-index, but it wont work and the logs say that both z-index are auto.
Why?

```
<div id="a" style="z-index=2; position:fixed; width:100%; height:40px; background:green;">
</div>

<div id="b" style="z-index=1; position: relative; width:100%; top:20px; height:100px; background:gray; left:40px;">
</div> 

<script>
console.log("a",window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("a")).zIndex);
console.log("b",window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("b")).zIndex);
</script>
```

If set by javascript it works:

```
document.getElementById("a").style.zIndex=2;
```

But z-index set inline wont work why?

Comment: z-index:2 not z-index=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have typo.

```
z-index=1
```

should becomes

```
z-index:1
```